# SQL query with two conditions, update the one matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table:

```
id fid nfid
1  10  44
2  44  5
3  18  8
```

Variables:

```
$oldid = 44;
$newid = 99;
```

Current query:

```
UPDATE Table SET fid = $newid WHERE fid = $oldid OR nfid = $oldid
```

This obviously updates the fid to $newid, but I want it to update fid OR nfid, whichever is matched in the WHERE clause. Is this possible to complete in one query, or do I have to do two updates?

Pseudo SQL:

```
UPDATE Table SET fid = $newid OR nfid = $newid WHERE fid = $oldid OR nfid = $oldid
```

Happy for any input. Thanks.

Comment: See my edited answer below. I have tested it, it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IF`, I also added there quotes, to read it better:

```
mysql_query("
  UPDATE Table
  SET
    fid = IF (fid = ".$oldid.", ".$newid.", fid),
    nfid = IF (nfid = ".$oldid.", ".$newid.", nfid)
";
```

Explanation:

if `fid = $oldid`, then it will do `fid = $newid`, otherwise it will leave value (`fid = fid`)

if `nfid = $oldid`, then it will do `nfid = $newid`, otherwise it will leave value (`nfid = nfid`)

Comment: Just tried it on my server and `UPDATE Table SET fid = IF (fid = 44, 99, fid), nfid = IF (nfid = 44, 99, nfid)` did exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: In another 22 seconds, according to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use two separate update statements?

```sql
UPDATE Table 
   SET fid = $newid 
 WHERE fid = $oldid
;

UPDATE Table 
   SET nfid = $newid
 WHERE nfid = $oldid
;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do some funky stuff with a `CASE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE Table
   SET nfid = CASE WHEN nfid = $oldid THEN $newid ELSE nfid END
      , fid = CASE WHEN  fid = $oldid THEN $newid ELSE  fid END
 WHERE nfid = $oldid
    OR  fid = $oldid
```

Comment: I wanted it to complete in one query, it's a learning kind of thing. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score -1):

I think its meant to be written like:

```
UPDATE Table SET fid = $newid, nfid = $newid WHERE fid = $oldid OR nfid = $oldid
```

So replace `OR` with a comma `,`

Comment: That would update both fields. I think the asker only wants to update whichever one matches the `WHERE` search.